# How to fetch images from NSDictionary to UICollectionView iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a dictionary with few images. It's structured like following.

`NSDictionary`

```
 |__ bed
 |    |__ 351.jpg
 |    |__ 352.jpg
 |__ pillow
 |    |__ pillow1.png
      |__ pillow2.png
```

I tried to add it to the `colloectioview` like following.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return self.imagesDictionary.count;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.imagesDictionary allValues] objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Setup cell identifier
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UIImage *image = (UIImage*)[[(NSArray*)[self.imagesDictionary allValues] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    recipeImageView.image = image;
    [cell addSubview:recipeImageView];
    // Return the cell
    return cell;
}
```

When I run this code, I got 2 sections and all section has same images(section1 - 351.jpg, pillow2.jpg, section2 - 351.jpg, pillow2.jpg). How can I fix this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: When you are creating the `UIImage` instance, try changing the code to `UIImage *image = (UIImage*)[[(NSArray*)[self.imagesDictionary allValues] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`  Get the object at the given section first, then look for the image of given row (in that section).

Comment: I'm guessing that you somehow put the same image into the dictionary twice.  Verify that the images actually are different, as stored in the dictionary.  But beyond that, as others have said, dictionaries are a poor primary structure for a "dataSource".  While normally `allValues` will return the values in the same order every time, it's not guaranteed.  Use arrays.

Comment: I've checked. images are different

Comment: Well, it's a dumb design.  Fix it before you go any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here likely stems from the fact that NSDictionary is not an ordered container. If you want to pick items from it by index, you need to sort the keys before indexing into them. Try something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return self.imagesDictionary.count;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray* sortedSections = [[self.imagesDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
    NSString* key = sortedSections[section];
    NSArray* images = self.imagesDictionary[key];
    return images.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Setup cell identifier
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    NSArray* sortedSections = [[self.imagesDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
    NSString* key = sortedSections[[indexPath indexAtPosition: 0]];
    NSArray* images = self.imagesDictionary[key];
    UIImage *image = (UIImage*) images[[indexPath indexAtPosition: 1]];
    recipeImageView.image = image;
    [cell addSubview:recipeImageView];
    // Return the cell
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: this fetches all images(4 images) inside each section. but i want to set 1st 2 images on 1st section and 2nd images set on 2nd section? is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure that your dictionary contains what you think it contains?

Comment: yes. those 4 images are fetched. Problem is both 4 images are showing in each page(there are 2 pages i have that can be scrolled).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest you to store the items on NSDictionary in this case as you would need to search for sections with index(e.g 0) and not key(e.g bed). Therefore I would suggest ordered collections(NSArray). 
Check this Topic:
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i)

Your main issue, seems to be this line of code:

```
UIImage *image = (UIImage*)[[(NSArray*)[self.imagesDictionary allValues] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

because

- the method allValues will not return the elements in a defined order
- you are using indexPath.row instead of indexPath.section.